# suexec policy violation

Tags: php, hosting, suexec

I developed a site on PHP and hosted it with iPage. it was working fine, but today I checked the site and it says:

```
The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling 
the request. The script had an error or it did not produce any output. If there 
was an error, you should be able to see it in the error log.
```

and the error log says:

```
20120423T060239: mydomain.com/file.php suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
```

I searched the error and it said to change permission to `755`, but it didn't worked. I read another article and it said to change permission for directories to `644` and files to `765`. but it failed too.

Please help me.

Comment: `see suexec log for more details` - did you do this? What did it say?

Comment: i am unable to locate suexec log on my web hosting site

Answer (score 1):

Correct file rights:

- directories  755
- php files  644